# which one is correct? "My test is the next day" or "My test is on the next day"?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

I want to know that whether both the sentences are same or means different?

> My test is the next day.

or

> My test is on the next day.

Comment: In almost all contexts *neither* are "valid" (it would always be expressed as *My test is **tomorrow***). But if you've contextually established some specific day ***in the future*** (the day ***after*** which is your test) you can either include the preposition ***on*** or not. It makes absolutely no difference to the meaning (I'd guess that more often we *wouldn't* include ***on***, but I've no particularly strong opinion on that). Equally common if not more so: *My test is **the day after***, where I'm almost certain including ***on*** would be very much a minority choice).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I understand the specifying future date or tomorrow will work out and is more correct. But I want to know the if the first one "My test is the next day" is correct. I mean, does it make sense or "on" should be used here for it to make sense?

Comment: "I shall get back from London on Monday, and my test is the next day."

Comment: I know there  will be *some* "false positive" matches, but [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+the+next+day%2Cis+on+the+next+day%2Cis+the+day+after&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20the%20next%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20on%20the%20next%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20the%20day%20after%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cis%20the%20next%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20on%20the%20next%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20the%20day%20after%3B%2Cc0) correctly reflects the fact that ***on*** is uncommon, and ***day after*** is *very* common in this context.